# UITableViewWrapperView and UITableView size differs with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am building a chat. Everything seem to be quite ok but I bumped into sort of 'buggy' problem.

i got UIViewController with UITextView bar for entering message and UITableView.
They are in this constraint: `"V:|-(64)-[chatTable][sendMessageBar]-(keyboard)-|"`.
When the keyboard is not out - the constant of this constraint is `0`. and after keyboard is out - i increase the constant to keyboard height.

when the keyboard is not out:

```
self.table.contentSize = (375.0,78.5)
self.table.bounds = (0.0,-490.0,375.0,568.5)
self.table.frame = (0.0,64.0,375.0,568.5)
self.table.subviews[0].frame (UITableViewWrapperView) = (0.0,0.0,375.0,568.5)
self.table.subviews[0].frame (UITableViewWrapperView) = (0.0,0.0,375.0,568.5)
```

and when the keyboard comes out:

```
self.table.contentSize = (375.0,78.5)
self.table.bounds = (0.0,-274.0,375.0,352.5
self.table.frame = (0.0,64.0,375.0,352.5)
self.table.subviews[0].frame (UITableViewWrapperView) = (0.0,-137.5,375.0,137.5)
self.table.subviews[0].frame (UITableViewWrapperView) = (0.0,0.0,375.0,137.5)
```

So the UITableViewWrapperView, after I increase constraints constant, differs in size to its superview - UITableView. Is there a way to fix this ? I would assume that `UITableViewWrapperView` would change its frame and bounds according to `UITableView` but it does not.

Any ideas where is the problem or how could I work around it ?

ADDING:

After some more research - it seems that it happens somewhere between `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is kinda weird tho:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    println("WrapperView Frame :991: \(self.table.subviews[0].frame)") \\ WrapperView Frame :991: (0.0,0.0,375.0,568.5)
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    println("WrapperView Frame :992: \(self.table.subviews[0].frame)") \\ WrapperView Frame :992: (0.0,0.0,375.0,568.5)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    println("WrapperView Frame :6: \(self.table.subviews[0].frame)") \\ WrapperView Frame :6: (0.0,-137.5,375.0,137.5)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    println(">> viewDidLayoutSubviews")
}
```

So it seems that something happens there that messes up the `UITableViewWrapperView`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following fixed it for me:

```
func fixTableViewInsets() {
    let zContentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    tableView.contentInset = zContentInsets
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = zContentInsets
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    fixTableViewInsets()
}
```

I discovered that at viewWillAppear() that the insets were all 0.  But at viewDidAppear(), they had been modified to apparently offset for navigation bar, etc.  This makes the UITableViewWrapperView different from the UITableView.
I changed the insets in its own routine so that it was easier to experiment with calling it from different places.  The viewWillLayoutSubviews() let it get changed before being presented - placing the change in viewDidAppear() caused the table to jerk.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this today and while the fix suggested by @anorskdev works nicely, it seems that the root cause of the issue is the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property of UIViewController, which is `true` by default. I turned it off in my storyboard and the problem went away. Look for the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" checkbox in the View Controller inspector and make sure it's unchecked.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that it is a bug (fighting with this bug took all day for me)
Finally [this](http://isenry.blogspot.ru/2013/08/ios7-tableview-layout-bug-with.html) workaround helped:

```
for (UIView *subview in tableView.subviews)
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"])
    {
        subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it one of the apple's forbidden API? (UITableViewWrapperView)

Answer (score 7):

After small investigation I have found this solution with setting all the `safeAreaInsets` and `layoutMargins` on the `UITableView` to zero:

Swift 4 snipset:

```html
class CustomTableView: UITableView {

 override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
  get {
   return .zero
  }
 }

 override var layoutMargins: UIEdgeInsets {
  get {
   return .zero
  }

  set {
   super.layoutMargins = .zero
  }
 }
}
```

The main problem is safeAreaInsets introduced in `tvOS 11.0` - the `UITableViewWrapperView` just took the properties from the parent view (UITableView) and renders the content with safeAreaInsets.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on tvOS 11.3, and neither of suggestions related with zero insets or scroll disable did the job, except looping through tableView's subviews and setting the *UITableViewWrapperView*'s frame to the tableView's frame.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        for view in tableView.subviews {
            if String(describing: type(of: view)) == "UITableViewWrapperView" {
                view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11 `UITableViewWrapperView` has gone, so this problem may occur only on later iOS versions. I faced it on iOS10 when I pushed custom `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController` stack.

So, the solution is to override property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` in custom view controller like this:

```
override var automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets: Bool {
    get {
        return false
    }
    set {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500831/1941338) given by [anorskdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203575/anorskdev)

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

**edit**: Turning off automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on the hosting ViewController, as suggested by [Steve Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658649/steve-roy) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673990/1941338), also worked and is the one I went with, as it seems cleaner to disable the behaviour rather than correcting it afterwards.