# How to adjust size of UITableViewWrapper to same size as UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

My problem is white space on top of TableView:

[image]

First I thought it is a header:

[image]

But not fixed then I chaged these even in code:

[image]

Finally I saw this is wrapper view in debugging:

[image]

I don't want to loop through subviews as suggested like this, even though it did not fix my problem:

```
for (UIView *subview in tableView.subviews)
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"])
    {
        subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height);
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening because I didn't have such a problem before!

Comment: I even tried to return float value in heightForHeaderInSection but did not work!

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671324/uitableviewwrapperview-and-uitableview-size-differs-with-autolayout

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem using

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section{
  return 0.01;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was solved by disabling Extend Edges: Under Top Bar in Storyboard.

[Extend Edges screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJfzk.png)

Or programmatically:

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

This will disable extending to any edge.