# difference in tableview and tableview wrapper view contentSize

Tags: ios

I have dynamic resizing cell `tableview`. i added leading space, trailing space, height, and top constraints to `tableview`.

after reloading tableview and `layoutIfNeeded`, i changed `tableview` height = `tableview` content size

**but my tableview actual content size based on cell size it's 111 but it is showing tableview content size as 170.**

if i check in debug inspector it's showing `tableview` content size as 111 and `tableview` wrapper size as 170. Because of tableview wrapper view size difference `fareBreakupTableviewHeight.constant = fareBreakupTableView.contentSize.height` giving wrong answer. can any one please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: did you check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671324/uitableviewwrapperview-and-uitableview-size-differs-with-autolayout

Comment: yes i Checked, but i have to call tableview reload only after response comes from the API. initially tableview height is 0.once response came i have to change tableview height to tableview content size

Comment: try by setting required height value to height 'constraint.constant' and call layoutIfNeeded

Comment: can you please show code and screenshot too

Comment: Thank u guys i got the issue. we have to give estimated row height less i.e 30. actually i gave 120.

Comment: @Manasa, post your solution as an answer.